# Qt - QTextEdit How to get an exact duplicate of the content just by its side

Tags: c++, qt

How to get QTextEdit to show the exact duplicate of its content just by its side, so that when printed on a single A4 Page same content will appear twice side by side just like a Mirror Image or something.

Currently this is how the QTextEdit content looks like

[image]

So the goal is to have this exact content shown again on its right in the same QTextEdit Dialog and print it.

How can this be achieved ? Been searching for a solution for weeks now but still can't get a solid idea that works.

This is what i'm trying to achieve or atleast print the content in this style with the content printed twice showing side by side in the same page..

Comment: I don't understand what your asking.

Comment: I think `ui->textEdit->toPlainText();`  is good enough for you.

Comment: This looks like a **homework question**. According to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) these questions **must** include a summary of the work done so far. "Been searching for a solution for weeks" does IMHO not qualify as such.

Comment: @Steve How to get a mirror image of the text in that QTextEdit just by its right side in the same Dialog

Comment: @Maxx It will return User entry `\n` (enter)  spaces '\r'  characters. you can save that QString and set it to another to see what happening.

Comment: You're not describing what you want very well - it's very ambiguous. Do you want to capture the graphics, flip it horizontally, and place it back in the window (just like a mirror), or something else? Take some time to describe what you want if you expect people to take the time to help you.

Comment: @Steve Ok attached a picture that should give a clear picture of what i'm trying to get printed... Same content shown twice in the same page side by side this is what i meant by it... Sorry for the trouble really...

Comment: This is actually a problem that i'm stuck with in the printing/output module of a Qt C++ application that is being developed for a client...

Comment: Might want to censor any private information (like the customer name). Otherwise, I can't help you with this problem, but thanks for posting more information.

Comment: Nah... Those are fake examples.. Yes i've been searching for the solution for several weeks now... Still can't figure it out... :-)